# Odd behavior with git, grep, and bash

Tags: git, bash

The command

```
$ git branch --contains HEAD
```

returns

```
* goofing_around
```

as I expect.  But I want to store this in a bash variable, so I run

```
$ bbb=$(git branch --contains HEAD)
```

and then I check the contents of `bbb` ...

```
$ echo $bbb
```

... and get ...

```
file1 file2 file3 goofing_around
```

(`file1` etc. are indeed files in the directory.)  What is going on?  How can I store just that first line that gives me the current branch name?

Comment: Nothing wrong with how you're storing it. What's wrong is how you're checking its contents.

Comment: BTW, http://shellcheck.net/ would have caught this for you.

Comment: As another aside, consider `declare -p bbb` as a more precise way to check what the variable `bbb` contains: Its output will tell you whether the variable is exported; whether it's an array; whether it's been set read-only, flagged as an integer, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotes are important: Unquoted expansions are string-split (broken into words on spaces, or characters in `IFS`) and glob-expanded (so a word containing only `*` is replaced with a list of filenames in the current directory).

```
echo "$bbb"
```